# Changed 120gb SSD to 256gb SSD for OS, no partition on other drives anymore

Tags: partitioning, fstab

My original ubuntu server OS was on a 120gb SSD. I decided to change the SSD to a bigger size.

I have 4 other HDDs in the system. After reinstalling the OS, I copied my old fstab file back to mount my HDDs but I got an error. Looking at gdisk, I can there is no partition table any longer.

I didn't realise I had to back up the parition tables. I have a lot of data on the drives.

How do I restore partition tables without formatting the drives again?

Comment: Copying an old `fstab` was a bad idea. You have to update UUIDs.

Comment: I did `ls /dev/disk/by-id` and the IDs are the same.

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair